# Writing a script that prints information about a directory

Tags: bash, directory, average, partition, drive

My script needs to take in a directory as its only argument, and then print out the following information:

- How full is the drive in which the directory is in? (%)
- How many files there is in the directory (inc. subdirectories), average file size and the full path to the largest file in that directory.
- Which file (not including directories) has the most hard links?

I'm completely lost and desperate. Please help!

Comment: Take a look at `man df` and `man find`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a simple script-- it seems a waste of time to code something so easy on here, but here are the commands to use in your script.  You should also man ls, and read about inodes and ln command.

```
df -k "$1"
ls -R $1| wc -l
ls -o $1/* | grep -v "^d" | sort -k2 | tail -1
```

Don't just turn this in-- learn the commands as you put them into a script.  If you don't understand each one in that last command, you are doing yourself a disservice.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response. I need to make the output look something like this:

The partition in which the directory is in is 47% full.
There are 142 files in the given directory. The biggest file is 42041 bytes. etc. Any idea how I can incorporate your answer to fit my desired output?

Comment: Remember quotes or this will fail for arguments with spaces.

Comment: @AmarŠukman I did 90% of the work for you-- I can't in good conscience do the rest.  Just find a page on how to script, and if you can assign a variable and "hello world", you can use the above commands to create the script.  I'll even edit and give you one with quotes per andlrc's advice so you can see how it's done.